# Disable writing in input type number HTML5

Tags: html

I want to disable writing into a field of type number, for avoiding strings data, and write just numbers, so how to enable scroll bars only  ?

```
<form>
 <input type="number"  path="note" min="1" max="20"/>
</form>
```

Comment: two are the same thing, i think what i want to do is clear, input of type number allow just numeric data so enable only scroll bars

Comment: Can't you just use the `readonly` attribute? It is supported for type number

Comment: @Souad 'disable writing in input type number HTML5' you must change the heading of your question it is misleading.

Comment: From a UX perspective: Isn't weird that a control appears as active (as we need the arrows), we can focus on the input, but then key strokes are ignored?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you are able/allowed to use jQuery, you can disable `keypress` on the `type='number'`.

```
$("[type='number']").keypress(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

This allows you to use up and down arrows on the input, but doesn't allow keyboard input.

Comment: Maybe something changed since '13, now keypress won't work for keys Delete and Backspace, this will all user to delete value, I used keydown that covers all

Comment: What's the use of disabling the keyboard ? who does it benefit ? If I'm trying to enter text into a number field then it's not probable that I would understand why my keyboard is broken. I hate it when UX "experts" force developers to do that.

Answer (score 32):

You can cancel KeyDown event using this

`<input type="number" onKeyDown="return false">`

Answer (score 5):

If I understood you correctly, I just implemented the same thing myself using vanilla Javascript (no jQuery).

```js
window.onload = () => {
  //add event listener to prevent the default behavior
  const mouseOnlyNumberInputField = document.getElementById("mouse-only-number-input");
  mouseOnlyNumberInputField.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="mouse-only-number-input" name="number" type="number" min="1" max="20" value="10" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//using this method can make a disabled writing on input type=number
```

```css
input {
  cursor: default;
  /*when hover it default pointer*/
  color: transparent;
  /*make blinking cursor disappear*/
  /*but it will make to text disappear*/
  text-shadow: 0px 0px black;
  /*when it disappear add text shadow to black*/
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="-32767" max="32767" onkeydown="return false //return value false" value="0">
<!--make an input-->
```

using this method with css and html to do that

Answer (score 0):

No Scrolling, no increment of numbers, max-length provided, no copy paste.

Check out the Fiddle below, which has the features needed within a type number form field.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal home" role="form" action="" method="post" id="payment-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<label for="number">Mobile number : </label>
<input class="form-control" id="number" name="number" type="number" data-rule-required="true" aria-required="true" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); this.value = this.value.replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==10 && event.keyCode!=8) return false;">
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

**[DEMO - JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/cwcjkyk4/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```js
//using this method can make a disabled writing on input type=number
```

```css
input {
  cursor: default;
  /*when hover it default pointer*/
  color: transparent;
  /*make blinking cursor disappear*/
  /*but it will make to text disappear*/
  text-shadow: 0px 0px black;
  /*when it disappear add text shadow to black*/
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="-32767" max="32767" onkeydown="return false //return value false" value="0">
<!--make an input-->
```

Answer (score 0):

In the onkeydown event, event.keyCode returns the ASCII code of the pressed key. The code for numeric keys 0-9 are 48-57. So, we can check if the pressed key is a number (between 0-9) and allow the event to proceed or not based on that

```
 <input type="number" path="note" min="1" max="20" onkeydown="return event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In js file :

```
$("[type='number']").keydown(function (e) {
        return (e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40) ? false: true;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for css solutions only:

```css
[type="number"] {
  pointer-events: none;
}

::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}


/* fallback for firefox: */
@supports (-moz-appearance: textfield) {
    [type="number"] {
        pointer-events: unset;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number">
```

Answer (score -4):

Firstly, your markup is incorrect. The form tags must surround the input tag:

```
<form name="my_form">
    <input ...code...
    <input ...code...
</form>
```

Secondly, if you are using HTML5 and want a number input, you can use this:

```
<input type="number" name="my_number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50"/>
```

(from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp))

Be aware that current browser implementations of the "number" input vary.

You then reference the value using Javascript, or have it posted using the form.

Comment: ...as for the bit about "scroll bars", I'm not sure what you mean!

Comment: how to disable the input so that user cant edit the form ,thats the question