# Min and max value of input in angular4 application

Tags: angular, input, max, min

I have an angular4 application with a form. In this one I have an input to enter a percentage. So, I want to block the input with value between 0 and 100.
I tried to add `min="0"` and `max="100"` but I can yet enter an number higher than 100 or smaller than 0.

**template**

```html
<md-input-container>
  <input type="number" 
    maxlength="3" 
    min="0" 
    max="100" 
    required 
    mdInput 
    placeholder="Charge" 
    [(ngModel)]="rateInput" 
    name="rateInput">
  <md-error>Required field</md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

Do you know how I can do this ?

Comment: Yes , it will you need to check for the error , it will not stop user to enter more then that , it will throw error on large number

Comment: If I get the error, how can I display an error like with md-error ?

Comment: That should not be marked duplicate, the answer on the post you provided is outdated. Angular 4 now supports min/max validators.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I succeeded by using a form control.
This is my html code :

```
<md-input-container>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="100" required mdInput placeholder="Charge" [(ngModel)]="rateInput" name="rateInput" [formControl]="rateControl">
    <md-error>Please enter a value between 0 and 100</md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

And in my Typescript code, I have :

```
this.rateControl = new FormControl("", [Validators.max(100), Validators.min(0)])
```

So, if we enter a value higher than 100 or smaller than 0, the material design input become red and the field is not validate. So after, if the value is not good, I don't save when I click on the save button.

Comment: Note: I discovered that I needed ReactiveFormsModule imported in my module to use this solution.

Comment: Commenting for Mateusz Adamczyk:


OK, I need to add a separate answer because I just created the account to write it down and cannot add a comment to @Adrien post. DON'T MIX REACTIVE FORM WITH TEMPLATE-DRIVEN FORM! I don't know why the hell he has most upvotes here. Just please, don't do it.

btw, the best solution I found for that case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52259458/10380064.

Comment: where to input the line "this.rateControl..." in type script? The constructor or ngOnInit() or somewhere?

Comment: Don't use this. Angular states: Note that support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives was deprecated in Angular v6 and is scheduled for removal in a future version of Angular. For details, see Deprecated features. from https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlDirective#use-with-ngmodel

Comment: @Pier Yes, you are right. But it's deprecated in Angular 6 and in my question it was for Angular v4. So for Angular 4, it's working.

Answer (score 29):

Actually when you use type="number" your input control populate with **up/down arrow** to increment/decrement numeric value, so when you update textbox value with those button it will **not pass limit of 100**, **but** when you **manually** give input like 120/130 and so on, it will **not validate for max limit**, so you have to validate it by code.

You can disable manual input OR you have to write some code on valueChange/textChange/key* event.

Comment: Woah! thats a bad thing isnt't thats like the most basic functionality or else whats the point of validation in angular ?

Comment: this is how you disable it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54348294/12097072. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution :

This is kind of hack , but it will work

```
<input type="number" 
placeholder="Charge" 
[(ngModel)]="rateInput" 
name="rateInput"
pattern="^$|^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1][0][0])?"
required 
#rateInput2 = "ngModel">

<div *ngIf="rateInput2.errors && (rateInput2.dirty || rateInput2.touched)"
    <div [hidden]="!rateInput2.errors.pattern">
        Number should be between 0 and 100
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the link to the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pYGFxtq13h7v0OuBJUvD?p=preview) , please have a look.

Comment: It works, but I use material design so I would have the same design that other inputs...

Comment: Nope it will also works with yours just put that input fields inplace of yours and try

Comment: No, I don't have the material design on it.

Comment: @VivekDoshi Yes it works great also in mat input feilds

Answer (score 3):

You can control with a change event if the input is within your range, if it is not in the range you assign 0.

```
<md-input-container>
  <input type="number" 
    maxlength="3" 
    min="0" 
    max="100" 
    required 
    mdInput 
    placeholder="Charge" 
    [(ngModel)]="rateInput"
    (change)= "rateInput < 0 ? rateInput = 0 : rateInput; rateInput > 100 ? rateInput = 0 : rateIntput;"
    name="rateInput">
  <md-error>Required field</md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: ...rateInput > 100 ? rateInput = 0 : rateIntput;

I thhink it will be better:
 rateInput > 100 ? rateInput = 100 : rateIntput;

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this in angular2+ by adding (onkeypress)

```
<input type="number" 
    maxlength="3" 
    min="0" 
    max="100" 
    required 
    mdInput 
    placeholder="Charge" 
    [(ngModel)]="rateInput"
    (onkeypress)="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"
    name="rateInput">
```

Tested on Angular 7

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a directive to listen the change event on the input and reset the value to the min value if it is too low. [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-usfbzh)

```
@HostListener('change') onChange() {
  const min = +this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('min');

  if (this.valueIsLessThanMin(min, +this.elementRef.nativeElement.value)) {
    this.renderer2.setProperty(
      this.elementRef.nativeElement,
      'value',
      min + ''
    );
  }
}
```

Also listen for the **ngModelChange** event to do the same when the form value is set.

```
@HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
onModelChange(value: number) {
  const min = +this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('min');
  if (this.valueIsLessThanMin(min, value)) {
    const formControl = this.formControlName
      ? this.formControlName.control
      : this.formControlDirective.control;

    if (formControl) {
      if (formControl.updateOn === 'change') {
        console.warn(
          `minValueDirective: form control ${this.formControlName.name} is set to update on change
          this can cause issues with min update values.`
        );
      }
      formControl.reset(min);
    }
  }
}
```

Full code:

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener,
  Optional,
  Renderer2,
  Self
} from "@angular/core";
import { FormControlDirective, FormControlName } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: directive-selector
  selector: "input[minValue][min][type=number]"
})
export class MinValueDirective {
  @HostListener("change") onChange() {
    const min = +this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute("min");

    if (this.valueIsLessThanMin(min, +this.elementRef.nativeElement.value)) {
      this.renderer2.setProperty(
        this.elementRef.nativeElement,
        "value",
        min + ""
      );
    }
  }

  // if input is a form control validate on model change
  @HostListener("ngModelChange", ["$event"])
  onModelChange(value: number) {
    const min = +this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute("min");
    if (this.valueIsLessThanMin(min, value)) {
      const formControl = this.formControlName
        ? this.formControlName.control
        : this.formControlDirective.control;

      if (formControl) {
        if (formControl.updateOn === "change") {
          console.warn(
            `minValueDirective: form control ${
              this.formControlName.name
            } is set to update on change
              this can cause issues with min update values.`
          );
        }
        formControl.reset(min);
      }
    }
  }

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>,
    private renderer2: Renderer2,
    @Optional() @Self() private formControlName: FormControlName,
    @Optional() @Self() private formControlDirective: FormControlDirective
  ) {}

  private valueIsLessThanMin(min: any, value: number): boolean {
    return typeof min === "number" && value && value < min;
  }
}
```

Make sure to use this with the form control set to **updateOn** blur or the user won't be able to enter a +1 digit number if the first digit is below the min value.

```
 this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    test: [
      null,
      {
        updateOn: 'blur',
        validators: [Validators.min(5)]
      }
    ]
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

[**I assume the reader has basic knowledge of Angular2+ and Forms**]

It is easy to show a numerical input and put the limits, but you have to also take care of things may happen out of your predictions.

1. Implement the tag in your 'html':

```
<input type="number" [min]="0.00" [max]="100.00" [step]="0.01" formControlName="rateFC">
```

2. But as [Adrien said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45484763/10570157), still user can enter manually a wrong number. You can validate input by [Validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) easily. In your '.ts':

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

//many other things...

this.myFG = new FormGroup({
   //other form controls...,
   rateFC  : new FormControl(0, [Validators.min(0), Validators.max(100)])
});
```

3. Up to now everything is ok, but it is better to let the user know the input is wrong, then draw a red line around the invalid input element by adding to your style:

```
.form-control.ng-touched.ng-invalid{
    border:2px solid red;
}
```

4. And to make it perfect, prevent the user to submit the wrong data.

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!myFG.valid">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a workaround with ngModelChange. In my case I wanted to avoid that users set a year earlier than current year. In html

```
<div class="col">
      <label>Year<span *ngIf="yearInvalid" class="badge badge-danger ml-1"> Year is invalid</span></label>

      <input class="form-control" type="number" id="year" name="year" #year="ngModel"
      [(ngModel)]="projection.year" required pattern="(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}"
      (ngModelChange)="checkYear($event)" />
</div>
```

And in angular I just check on model change:

```
checkYear(e) {
    if (e < new Date().getFullYear()) {
      this.yearInvalid = true;
    }
    else {
      this.yearInvalid = false;
    }
  }
```

I think it can work very good with 0-100 or any other check that you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple approach in Template driven forms for min/max validation with out using reactive forms and building any directive, would be to use pattern attribute of html. This has already been explained and answered here please look
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63312336/14069524

Answer (score -10):

If you are looking to validate length use `minLength` and `maxLength` instead.