# Input Box value should not take value more than 100 but it is taking and it is not in a form

Tags: html, forms

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="100" #weightCQ="ngModel"   style="width:80px" placeholder="Weightage" [(ngModel)]="weightage[j]">
```

Here the input should not take a value more than 100

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: ngModel? Maybe this answer could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480004/min-and-max-value-of-input-in-angular4-application

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Please correct your question.

Comment: it will take the values but when  you will try to submit the form it will show the error

Comment: @Raahul I guess my question is correct, SO has tons of question and answers on this topic, OP should have search it first instead of posting this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-limit-possible-inputs-in-a-html5-number-element)

Comment: It is not inside a form , just an input field in an diaglog box which is not having form , user should not be able to add number more than 100 manually which is not happening

Comment: @AdityaLamba You can try this in jquery -> `$('#yournumberboxid').keyup(function(){
  if ($(this).val() > 100){
    alert("plzz enter number less then 100");
    
  }
});`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this with jquery

```js
$('#100').keyup(function(){
 if($('#100').val() > 100) {
 $('#100').val(100);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="quantity" id="100" min="0" max="100" #weightCQ="ngModel"   style="width:80px" placeholder="Weightage" [(ngModel)]="weightage[j]">
```