# Prevent input field from any changes except with arrow buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to prevent completely users to modify the values of the number input form in any way that is not using the arrows in the form. Basically I have this:

```js
const pwEl = document.getElementById("pw");
const copyEl = document.getElementById("copy");
const lenEl = document.getElementById("len");
const upperEl = document.getElementById("upper");
const numberEl = document.getElementById("number");
const symbolEl = document.getElementById("symbol");
const generateEl = document.getElementById("generate");
const footerEl = document.getElementById("footer");


const lowerLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
const upperLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
const numbers = "1234567890"
const specialCharacters = "|@#~€!$%&/()=?¿"


function randomUpper() {
    return upperLetters[Math.floor(Math.random()*upperLetters.length)];
}

function randomNumbers() {
    return numbers[Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length)];
}

function randomSpecial() {
    return specialCharacters[Math.floor(Math.random()*specialCharacters.length)];
}

function randomLower() {
    return lowerLetters[Math.floor(Math.random()*lowerLetters.length)];
}


function generateChunk() {
    const xs = [];
    xs.push(randomLower());
    if (upperEl.checked) {
        xs.push(randomUpper());
    }
    if (numberEl.checked) {
        xs.push(randomNumbers());
    }
    if (symbolEl.checked) {
        xs.push(randomSpecial());
    }
    return xs[Math.floor(Math.random()*xs.length)];
}


function generatePassword() {
    const len = lenEl.value;
    let password = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        password += generateChunk();
    }
    pwEl.innerText = password;
}

function copy() {
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value = pwEl.textContent;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    textArea.remove();

    //adding class to transition 
    footerEl.innerText = "Succesfully copied to clipboard!";
    footerEl.classList.add("footer-active");
    setTimeout(() => {
        footerEl.classList.remove("footer-active");
    }, 1000)
    setTimeout(() => {
        footerEl.innerText = "";
    }, 1200);
}

generateEl.addEventListener("click", generatePassword);

copyEl.addEventListener("click", copy);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@500&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color:#37505c;
    color: #FFEAD0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.pw-container{
    background-color: #113537;
    width:500px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index:2;

}

.pw {
    background-color:#37505c;
    height: 70px;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.pw button{
    font-family: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -20%);
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease, transform 0.2s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pw:hover button {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, -90%)
}

.pw-header {
    padding: 1rem;
}

.pw-body {
    padding: 0 1rem 1rem;
}

.form-control {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0.5rem;
}

.generate {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display:block;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding : 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}


.footer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#113537;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
    z-index: 1;

}

.footer-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 0%);
    z-index: 1;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Password Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="pw-container">
        <div class="pw-header">
            <div class="pw">
                <span id="pw">1234</span>
                <button id="copy">Copy to clipboard</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="pw-body">
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="len">Length</label>
                <input id="len" onKeyDown="return false" type="number" min="5" max="20" value="7">
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="upper">Uppercase</label>
                <input id="upper" type="checkbox">
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="number">Numbers</label>
                <input id="number" type="checkbox">
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="symbol">Symbols</label>
                <input id="symbol" type="checkbox">
            </div>

            <button class="generate" id="generate">
                Generate Password
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" class="footer">
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Note that in the input, I added `onKeyDown="return false"`, an answer in other post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164278/disable-writing-in-input-type-number-html5) one.
However, this is not going to prevent the user from doing a paste of any value he wants, nor moving a value with the mouse into the field. Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: Could you use the onChange to allow only changes of 1 ?

Comment: Make it `readonly` or `disabled`…?

Comment: @deceze I want the user only to be able to modify it with the arrows, so this is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily block any events you want with event handlers like this - it takes a  list of events and adds an event handler for each to block it. You can add as many or few events as you need - [see a list of Events here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events):

```
"keypress paste dragstart drop cut".split(" ").forEach(function(e){
    lenEl.addEventListener(e, function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Working Example - Accessible Version: Allows tab and arrow keys**

```js
const pwEl = document.getElementById("pw");
const copyEl = document.getElementById("copy");
const lenEl = document.getElementById("len");
const upperEl = document.getElementById("upper");
const numberEl = document.getElementById("number");
const symbolEl = document.getElementById("symbol");
const generateEl = document.getElementById("generate");
const footerEl = document.getElementById("footer");


const lowerLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
const upperLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
const numbers = "1234567890"
const specialCharacters = "|@#~€!$%&/()=?¿"

"keypress paste dragstart drop cut".split(" ").forEach(function(e){
    lenEl.addEventListener(e, function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});

function randomUpper() {
    return upperLetters[Math.floor(Math.random()*upperLetters.length)];
}

function randomNumbers() {
    return numbers[Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length)];
}

function randomSpecial() {
    return specialCharacters[Math.floor(Math.random()*specialCharacters.length)];
}

function randomLower() {
    return lowerLetters[Math.floor(Math.random()*lowerLetters.length)];
}


function generateChunk() {
    const xs = [];
    xs.push(randomLower());
    if (upperEl.checked) {
        xs.push(randomUpper());
    }
    if (numberEl.checked) {
        xs.push(randomNumbers());
    }
    if (symbolEl.checked) {
        xs.push(randomSpecial());
    }
    return xs[Math.floor(Math.random()*xs.length)];
}


function generatePassword() {
    const len = lenEl.value;
    let password = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        password += generateChunk();
    }
    pwEl.innerText = password;
}

function copy() {
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value = pwEl.textContent;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    textArea.remove();

    //adding class to transition 
    footerEl.innerText = "Succesfully copied to clipboard!";
    footerEl.classList.add("footer-active");
    setTimeout(() => {
        footerEl.classList.remove("footer-active");
    }, 1000)
    setTimeout(() => {
        footerEl.innerText = "";
    }, 1200);
}

generateEl.addEventListener("click", generatePassword);

copyEl.addEventListener("click", copy);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@500&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color:#37505c;
    color: #FFEAD0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.pw-container{
    background-color: #113537;
    width:500px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index:2;

}

.pw {
    background-color:#37505c;
    height: 70px;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.pw button{
    font-family: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -20%);
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease, transform 0.2s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pw:hover button {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, -90%)
}

.pw-header {
    padding: 1rem;
}

.pw-body {
    padding: 0 1rem 1rem;
}

.form-control {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0.5rem;
}

.generate {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display:block;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding : 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}


.footer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#113537;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
    z-index: 1;

}

.footer-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 0%);
    z-index: 1;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Password Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="pw-container">
        <div class="pw-header">
            <div class="pw">
                <span id="pw">1234</span>
                <button id="copy">Copy to clipboard</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="pw-body">
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="len">Length</label>
                <input id="len" type="number" min="5" max="20" value="7">
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="upper">Uppercase</label>
                <input id="upper" type="checkbox">
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="number">Numbers</label>
                <input id="number" type="checkbox">
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="symbol">Symbols</label>
                <input id="symbol" type="checkbox">
            </div>

            <button class="generate" id="generate">
                Generate Password
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" class="footer">
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Blocking ALL Key Presses**

**Note that it is not recommended to prevent all keyDown/keyUp events, for accesibility reasons** - it makes your form impossible to use without mouse/touch screen - not only are you unable to change the values, you get *stuck inside that input forever* and can't even tab out of it! \

Therefore I use `keypress` instead of `keydown` above, as `keypress` allows for control keys to work but if you *really* need to, you can use `keydown` instead.

Working Example Blocking ALL Key Presses (inaccessible for visually impaired users)

```js
const pwEl = document.getElementById("pw");
const copyEl = document.getElementById("copy");
const lenEl = document.getElementById("len");
const upperEl = document.getElementById("upper");
const numberEl = document.getElementById("number");
const symbolEl = document.getElementById("symbol");
const generateEl = document.getElementById("generate");
const footerEl = document.getElementById("footer");


const lowerLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
const upperLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
const numbers = "1234567890"
const specialCharacters = "|@#~€!$%&/()=?¿"

"keydown paste dragstart drop cut".split(" ").forEach(function(e){
    lenEl.addEventListener(e, function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});

function randomUpper() {
    return upperLetters[Math.floor(Math.random()*upperLetters.length)];
}

function randomNumbers() {
    return numbers[Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length)];
}

function randomSpecial() {
    return specialCharacters[Math.floor(Math.random()*specialCharacters.length)];
}

function randomLower() {
    return lowerLetters[Math.floor(Math.random()*lowerLetters.length)];
}


function generateChunk() {
    const xs = [];
    xs.push(randomLower());
    if (upperEl.checked) {
        xs.push(randomUpper());
    }
    if (numberEl.checked) {
        xs.push(randomNumbers());
    }
    if (symbolEl.checked) {
        xs.push(randomSpecial());
    }
    return xs[Math.floor(Math.random()*xs.length)];
}


function generatePassword() {
    const len = lenEl.value;
    let password = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        password += generateChunk();
    }
    pwEl.innerText = password;
}

function copy() {
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value = pwEl.textContent;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    textArea.remove();

    //adding class to transition 
    footerEl.innerText = "Succesfully copied to clipboard!";
    footerEl.classList.add("footer-active");
    setTimeout(() => {
        footerEl.classList.remove("footer-active");
    }, 1000)
    setTimeout(() => {
        footerEl.innerText = "";
    }, 1200);
}

generateEl.addEventListener("click", generatePassword);

copyEl.addEventListener("click", copy);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@500&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color:#37505c;
    color: #FFEAD0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.pw-container{
    background-color: #113537;
    width:500px;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index:2;

}

.pw {
    background-color:#37505c;
    height: 70px;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.pw button{
    font-family: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -20%);
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease, transform 0.2s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pw:hover button {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, -90%)
}

.pw-header {
    padding: 1rem;
}

.pw-body {
    padding: 0 1rem 1rem;
}

.form-control {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0.5rem;
}

.generate {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display:block;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding : 0.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}


.footer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#113537;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
    z-index: 1;

}

.footer-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 0%);
    z-index: 1;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Password Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="pw-container">
        <div class="pw-header">
            <div class="pw">
                <span id="pw">1234</span>
                <button id="copy">Copy to clipboard</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="pw-body">
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="len">Length</label>
                <input id="len" type="number" min="5" max="20" value="7">
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="upper">Uppercase</label>
                <input id="upper" type="checkbox">
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="number">Numbers</label>
                <input id="number" type="checkbox">
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="symbol">Symbols</label>
                <input id="symbol" type="checkbox">
            </div>

            <button class="generate" id="generate">
                Generate Password
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" class="footer">
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

---

*Note, you no longer need the `onkeydown` or other event handlers on the input itself in either of these examples*

Comment: This works with the paste, but it doesn't prevent for the user to move a value inside the field with the mouse

Comment: @Norhther We can add any number of events you want to block, I'd just caution blocking  everything by default because it *will* affect accessibility for the visually impaired etc. I'll update my answer for this also, and I will suggest a way to prevent content being entered by keypress but still allowing control key presses - blocking all key presses means you're stuck in that input forever!!

Comment: Oh, I see. Works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By using event listeners, if the user focuses on the input then blur:

**jQuery:**

```js
$("input").on("focus", function() {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

**Vanilla:**

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input#len");

input.addEventListener("focus", function() {
    input.blur();
});
```

Comment: I would like to stick with vanilla js here

Comment: See the vanilla js implementation above

Comment: Same problem. You can still drag arbitrary input with the mouse.